# Can't reset route react native navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router, native, react-native-navigation

I can't clear my routing history, i try this but he puts that i don't know why. Can you help me pls :)                                                                                                          e

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Text, TouchableOpacity, Image} from 'react-native';
import Input from '../../components/Input/Input';
import {DismissKeyboard} from '../../components/DismissKeyboard/DismissKeyboard';
import Button from '../../components/Button/Button';
import Logo from '../../../assets/img/logo2.png';
import {StackActions, NavigationActions} from 'react-navigation';

class Login extends Component {
  onDone = () => {
    const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
      index: 0,
      key: null,
      actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({routeName: 'Register'})],
    });
    this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
  };

  static navigationOptions = (navigation) => ({
    header: null,
  });

  render() {
    return (
      <DismissKeyboard>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Image source={Logo} style={styles.image} />
          <Input placeholder="Numéro de téléphone ou adresse mail" />
          <Input placeholder="Mot de passe" />
          <Button text="Connexion" />
          <Text>Mot de passe oublié ?</Text>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.register} onPress={this.onDone}>
            <Text style={styles.registerText}>Inscription</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </DismissKeyboard>
    );
  }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZzAK.jpg)

Comment: i add an image of my error :)

Comment: Maybe [this thread](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/325) will help